# Как быстро внести 1E10 записей в базу данных?

Tags: mysql, sql, qt5, база-данных

Встал вопрос хранения данных, в количестве порядка 1E10 записей. Скорость выполнения `INSERT` в MySQL в среднем 0,05 с. Запись представляет собой 2 числа типа `double` и `float`.

**Upd:**

1. Можно ли запихнуть данные быстрее последовательных `INSERT`?
2. Может, это конкретно MySQL мне не подходит?
3. В виде бинарника не хотелось бы.
4. Операции запись, чтение, и очень хотелось бы `AVG`.
5. Данные поступают с устройства в виде массивов типа `float`, к каждому полученному числу вычисляется число типа `double`.
6. Вместо `MySQL` попробовал `Sqlite`, скорость возросла в 10 раз.

Comment: Как я понял вопрос не в хранении, а можно ли добавить кучу записей быстрее чем последовательные INSERT?

Comment: сформулируйте, пожалуйста, то, что вы написали, в виде вопроса.

Comment: Какие операции с ними будут выполняться, помимо хранения и чтения? Может, вообще хранить в бинарном файле: 8 байт на dbl + 4 байта на float = 12e10B ~= 111Gb.

Comment: В вопросе следует уточнить, в коком виде имеются эти записи. Либо, с какой целью они добавляются и генерируются ли каким-либо образом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL директива [`LOAD DATA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) позволяет очень быстро [загрузить данные из текстового файла](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/loading-tables.html).

Нужно создать таблицу, и подготовить текстовый файл с данными. Значения через табуляцию, NULL обозначается `\N`, одна строка в файле – одна строка в файле.

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/peace/data.txt' INTO TABLE table1;
```

Если вы на платформе Windows и разделитель строк в файле виндовый, то так:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/peace/data.txt' INTO TABLE table1
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```